# How to plot one pandas dataframe on top of another (capped by one)

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, matplotlib, plot

I have two panda dataframes:

```
print(df.change)

 date          % change
2020-04-13    0.00000
2020-04-14   -1.00230
2020-04-15   -1.29039
```

I'd like to plot this on a line graph with the date on the X axis. I'd then like to plot this other pandas dataframe on this same graph without altering the X axis scale.

```
print(hist.change)

 date         % change
2020-04-10    0.000000
2020-04-11   -2.171265
2020-04-12    0.000000
2020-04-13   -0.007166
2020-04-14    1.386600
2020-04-15    2.848441
2020-04-16    2.375493
```

So I'd only like it to plot the points where there is a corresponding df.change date. So only the days 13, 14 and 15 because only those days are available in the original plot. (only want the 3 dates on the x axis). Apologies for explaining this quite badly but I hope you can understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should convert both date columns to `datetime` type with `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: I then get an error saying index type not supported

Comment: Do that and `ax = df.change.plot(); hist.change.plot(ax=ax)`.

Comment: `df.merge(hist, on='date', how='outer').set_index('date').plot()`

Comment: `pd.to_datetime` managed to solve the index type not supported issue and I can now plot both graphs. However it is still stretched out: [link](https://imgur.com/a/eXSsU9Y). `ax = df.change.plot(); hist.change.plot(ax=ax)` does not seem to change it. And also the merge comment suggested by @piRSquared doesn't seem to work as the date column is actually an index. @Quang